# If $5^{a_{n+1} - a_n} = 1+\frac{1}{n+\frac 23} $, and $a_1=1$ then prove that $[a_{207} ] =3$ (Greatest integer function)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am going to skip through the exhausting computation part to get my result
$$a_{n+1} -a_1= \log_{5} (\frac{5+3n}{5})$$
Using $n+1 \to n$
$$\implies a_n-1 =\log_5 \frac { 2+3n}{5}$$

So $a_{207}$ is
$$a_{207} = 1+\log_5 \frac{623}{5}$$

It would be a shame to see that I came this far but got stuck at the final part of answer, ie. calculation of the logarithm, but here we are. I am not supposed to have a calculator or a log table at my disposal, so how can I guess the value?

Comment: I guess it is a typo, but in the last line you swap 5 with 3. Edit: And in the second line you swap 2 with 5.

Comment: $623/3=207.6$ , also $5^3=125$ , $5^4=625$, can you proceed?

Comment: @Cornman I merely replaced $n+1 \to n$

Comment: @Aditya Ah, I see. Sorry.

Comment: @Aditya The value is $3.99801$.  Rounding $a_{207}$ to the next integer gives $4$. Its floor is $3$. Your first and last line contain a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use the fact that $5^3 < 623 < 5^4$, so that $5^3/5 < 623/5 < 5^4/5$, and hence
$$\log_5  5^3/5 < \log_5 623/5 < \log_5 5^4/5$$
In other words, $2 < \log_5 623/5 < 3$. Thus
$$\lfloor a_{207} \rfloor = \lfloor 1 + \log_5 623/5 \rfloor$$
$$= 3$$

Answer (score 2):

To compute without a calculator, table etc $$a_{207}=1+\log_5\frac{623}{5}= 1 + \log_5\,623 -\log_5\,5=\log_5\,623<\log_5\,625=4$$
or $\log_5\,623<4$.  Thus $\lfloor a_{207}\rfloor=3$.

Comment: @Aditya $a_{207}=3.998008540171715$, Also sprach  $Wolfram\; Mathematica$